# How to make an onlick event handler as a class method

Tags: javascript

I want to create a JavaScript class that has an onclick event handler as a method:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var foo = new Foo();
  foo.load();
});
function Foo() {
  function clicked() {
    alert('clicked');
  }
  this.load = function () {
    $('#container').html('<button onclick="clicked()">Press</button>');  
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get a scope error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked is not defined**.

Why? How do I fix the scope and keep the event handler as a method of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the button as an object, and assign the click handler directly:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var foo = new Foo();
  foo.load();
});
function Foo() {
  function clicked() {
    alert('clicked');
  }
  this.load = function () {
    var b = $('<button>');
    b.text('Press');
    b.on('click', clicked);
    $('#container').append(b);  
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Doing it this way keeps a reference directly to the function itself, as it's always in scope.  By assigning it through the `onclick` attribute, it loses the scope of where it was declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by making a direct link to the function:

```
$('#container').html('<button>Press</button>').find('button').click(clicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

        foo.load();
});
var foo = new Foo();
function Foo() 
{
this.clicked=clicked;
function clicked() 
{
        alert('clicked');
}

this.load = function () 
{
        $('#container').html('<button onclick="foo.clicked();">Press</button>');  
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```